# Querying Answers

Tags: support, answers, search, api

Is it possible to use the Stack Exchange V2.2 API to search answers to questions to see if an answer contains a certain string?  For example, I want to send over a line of code to see if it has been copied from an answer, without knowing the question or having any other context about the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is just to use the [search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search) and include the term `is:answer` (from the [help page on searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)), e.g. [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NullPointerException+is%3Aanswer) returns only answers containing `NullPointerException`.

It *is* possible to use the API for this; the `q` parameter supports (roughly) the same syntax as the search box on the site. You can experiment on [this page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=NullPointerException%20is%3Aanswer&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) to see what URL you need; the URL corresponding to the search above is `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/excerpts?order=desc&sort=activity&q=NullPointerException%20is%3Aanswer&site=stackoverflow`.